# Sequential diode and capacitor - low vs high capacitance

Tags: capacitor, diodes, sequential-logic

Here is my circuit:
[Diode and capacitor](https://www.multisim.com/content/iQPhq3p78pzdn3dyhvAoEQ/diode-plotting/)

When I set capacitor to 1F I get the following voltage graph:
[image: High Capacitance]

When I set capacitor to 1pF I get the following voltage graph:
[image: Low Capacitance]

Why do I get this totally different behaviour? My diode had zero resitance ance saturation current is 0.00001A. I am also new to Multisim and for some reason when I change limit of time scale to something greater than 10 mS it reverts back to 10mS.

UPDATE:

Here is a graph with current:
Capacitance = 1F
[image: High capacitance VI]
Because of initial spike in current, it is hard to see later values of current. But at the end of the graph, flat area is around -10 uA and bump is 38 A

Capacitance = 1pF
[image: Low capacitance]

Comment: What is the reactance of the capacitor at the driven frequency? What is the reactance of the diode's capacitance, or its equivalent resistance (given its IS parameter)?

Comment: @TimWilliams. I cannot find reactance of capacitor in Multisim. I can only try to compute it like 1/2 pi * f * c. I am not sure what equivalent resistance either. Multisim provides RS (Ohmic resistance) which I set to zero.

Comment: Yes, that is the formula you need for reactance. Well, and some parenthesis. Do you know the equation for a diode? How about measuring it? You could apply a small voltage, at whatever frequency, and measure the current through it.

Comment: Are you sure the 1st graph is one farad and the 2nd graph is one picofarad? Some of these simulators (like LTspice) interpret **1F** as one femtofarad. If those graphs have switched labels, that might explain it.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I added plot with current. Is this helpful?

Comment: @glen_geek, in Multisim letter F is fixed, so it should be Farad, I can only control p, n, m and other letters in front of Farad.

Comment: What's the capacitance of the diode?

Comment: @Hearth Unfortunately, I do not know how to look it up in Multisim. It is not immediately listed. I found a link, but is a bit overwhelming: https://www.multisim.com/help/components/diode/diode-model/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your diode has additional properties that can typically be ignored in most cases, notably, reverse recovery time and reverse leakage (frequency real slow, output capacitance real high, respectively). However, in your case these properties can't be ignored with 10^-12 Farads of capacitance.

Reverse recovery time has to do with phenomena relating to charge carriers in the PN junction needing time to diffuse back to their respective junction (doped silicon). During this recovery time, the junction is "hot" and can conduct current in both directions. This is in contrast to an ideal rectifier. This is also a transient effect that occurs during the forward-bias to reverse-bias transition. After this transient settles, the next effect takes over...

Reverse leakage current is simply the current that flows (leaks) through the diode when the diode is reverse-biased. This is a steady-state parameter. This is also in contrast to an ideal diode - ideal diodes don't leak.

After doing the math (i/C = dv/dt), you will realize a tiny bit of current will cause a great change in potential across a tiny capacitor. In your 1F arrangement, these two effects are still present, but with a massive 1F capacitor, the effects are negligible, and you won't measure them.

Comment: I forgot to mention the capacitance of the diode will dominate WRT to a 1pF load cap.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I am not sure I completely understand what capacitance of diode means? Does diode act as capacitor? If I delete my main capacitor, will I still observe the same effect?

Comment: Yes. If you delete your capacitor you will see the same effect - you will be running "no load"/open circuit.

Comment: The capacitance of the diode is the capacitance of the PN junction - the capacitance of the diode itself (think of it as a capacitor across an ideal diode). It will be appreciable when your load capacitance is so small. You will be creating a capacitive voltage divider with your diode and the load capacitor.

Comment: I just tried deleting capacitor and my current spiked to terra territory. Do you think this is peculiarity of Multisim simulation?

Comment: Something's wrong. You shouldn't have any current at all without the capacitor. Put at least a 10M resistor as a load so you actually have a circuit. Some of these simulators need complete circuits to find proper operating points.

Comment: I put wire in place of my capacitor, so there is closed circuit, it just have no load besides diode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148788/discussion-between-mosfet-and-user1700890).